# update a mySQL table using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have written some C# to update a MySql table but I get an exception every time I call  the method ExecuteNonQuery(). I have researched this on the web and every solution I find produces the same error. I have an open connection to the database and the update query to the database is written correctly. The code that I have so far come up with is :

```
public int executeUpdate()
{
  int result = 0;
  if (isConnected)
  {
    try
    {
      MySqlConnection cn = new  MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

      cmd.Connection = cn; 
      cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET status_id = 1 WHERE test_id = 1";
      int numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    catch (MySqlException exSql)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine("Error - SafeMySql: SQL Exception: " + query);
      Console.Error.WriteLine(exSql.StackTrace);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine("Error - SafeMySql: Exception: " + query);
      Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
  }
  else
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error - SafeMySql: executeQuery failed. Not connected to DB");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your try section to the code below:

```
try
{
    using(MySqlConnection cn = new  MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    {        
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn; 
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET status_id = 1 WHERE test_id = 1";
        cn.Open();
        int numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose(); 
     }
}
```

The connection must be opened before you execute a command. In the example above the command object will immediately be disposed and the connection object will implcitly be closed and disposed when you leave the using section.

Comment: Thanks for posts guys its much apprciated. I have changed my code to what Espen Burud suggested and the code still throws an exception the exception is:  '{"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"}' . This exception is thrown when I pass over the cn.Open(); line.  Again I have had a good play and look on the web but can't find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: It's many situations that can cause access denied errors, so I think this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html page might help.

Comment: @user498213 This question isnt about access problems. You should pick out an answer according to your question.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't see the connection being opened**.

Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx): even inside a using block, they open the connection explicitly

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: The principle is the same for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) as it is for SQL Server:

```
public void CreateMySqlCommand(string myExecuteQuery, MySqlConnection myConnection) 
{
  MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(myExecuteQuery, myConnection);
  myCommand.Connection.Open();
  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is mysql instead of MSSQL.